# How do you tell if a user is logged in as root on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, sudo, root

If I sudo /bin/bash, the who and w command does not show a root login on Mac OS X.  How do you enable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a log in the /var/log directory called auth.log where you can see if somebody su or sudo to root.

```
Dec 23 00:32:43 hostname su: user to root on /dev/pts/3
```